# What should i add to the following code so that it can save button value onclick in php variable and i will send it in the email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Actually, i making a form and have many buttons in the form so I want to know that how it can be done whether when I click the button during form submission it will store that button value and after click to the final submit button a mail will send all input field values including button values that I have clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#frmemail').submit(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      data: $('#frmemail').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $('.success').fadeIn(1000)
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
     <?php
   if (isset($_POST['garden']))
   {
     $but= $_POST['garden'];
   }
 ?>
 <?php
$name = $_POST['form_name'];
$email = $_POST['form_email'];
$message = $_POST['form_msg'];
$garden = $_POST['garden'];
$to = "admin@rsfcrm.com";
$subject = "RIA Emails";
$body = "Name: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nGarden".$but."\nMessage:".$message;
$headers = "From: ". $email;
    if (mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers))
{echo "<script>window.alert('Successfull!');
    </script>";  
}else
{echo "<script>window.alert('Fialed');
    </script>"; 
}?>    
<div class="container">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmemail" method="post" action="test2">
    <fieldset class="margin-b">
      <legend>Contact Me</legend>
      <label for="form_name">Name:<input name="form_name" type="text" value="" required autofocus ></label>
      <label for="form_email">Email:<input name="form_email" type="email" value=""></label>
      <label for="form_msg">Message:<textarea name="form_msg" rows="5"></textarea></label>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="garage" name="garden" value="gardening">button</button>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  </section>
</div>  </body>`
```

Comment: Create a variable that holds values of clicked buttons, then add it to serialized data before posting.

Comment: can you show me with code because that's not sending value.

Comment: You would have to add onclick events to buttons that write to the variable, if you want to continue with this approach instead of hidden fields write some code and ask for more help when you have a more specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and hidden variable functionality.
like on first button click store value in hidden field and on second button click submit form. if you want code then i can paste here

Comment: yeah please, one thing I want to confirm that with the button I don't want it with input type = submit i want it with button type = button

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='hidden' name='garage_val' id='garage_val' value='' />
<script>
$("#garage").click(function(){
    $("#garage_val").val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: now on php side you have to check value for `garage_val`

Comment: main thing is that after button click how i will acces that value and send it in mail like php

Answer (score 0):

In your `form` add this input field

```
<input type='hidden' name='gardening' value='gardening' />
```

In your Php code

```
<?php
$gardening= $_POST['gardening'];
echo $gardening;
?>
```

Jquery

```
 $('#frmemail').submit(function(event) {
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'yourphpfilename.php',
          data: $('#frmemail').serialize(),
          success: function() {
            alert(data)
          }
        });
      });
```

No jquery click functions are required to do this,this value will be passed along with the form,hope this helps

**(Or)**

If you wish the value to be passed only on button click use this

Html

```
<input type='hidden' name='gardening'  class="hidden"/>
```

Jquery

```
$("#garage").click(function(e)
{ 
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.hidden').val('gardening');
});
```

Comment: Awesome dear thanks for your cooperation just tell me now how i will send this value in php like:                                                                                                                                                                     
echo $gardening;   how i will do it i want to save that value in php variable when a user clicks on that button and i want echo that value in php variable.i hope you got it???

Comment: @Hsherazch in ajax success:function(data){alert(data)}